# How to clone unused space only of an Ext4 partition

Tags: clone

How to make an image of free space of an Ext4 partition?

Per example: A 10GB partition has 5GB of allocates files, I need to make a raw image of the other 5GB free/unallocated space/data left.

Comment: ...why? If you don't mind me asking? IIRC ext4 has a hard structure with some blocks (of the underlying disk) used/usable for file data, with others used for inodes or other fs metadata. I wonder if you could use `debugfs` to list the numbers of the unused data blocks (though the numbering may be different from the numbering of the sectors on the underlying disk). Well, similarly, you could check unused inodes, but I think those are cleared when the fs is created.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `dumpe2fs -x /dev/your_partition` to get a list of `Free blocks` in a well-parseable format:

```bsh
# preparation
truncate -s 100M ext4.img
mkfs.ext4 ext4.img
partition=ext4.img

# test
dumpe2fs -x "${partition}"
```

yields

```
…
  Free blocks: 0x00014001-0x00016000
  Free inodes: 0x00004d31-0x000054e8
Group 11: (Blocks 0x00016001-0x00018000) csum 0xd1b4 [INODE_UNINIT, BLOCK_UNINIT, ITABLE_ZEROED]
  Block bitmap at 0x0000010e (bg #0 + 269), csum 0x00000000
  Inode bitmap at 0x0000011b (bg #0 + 282), csum 0x00000000
  Inode table at 0x00000bba-0x00000cb0 (bg #0 + 3001)
  8192 free blocks, 1976 free inodes, 0 directories, 1976 unused inodes
  Free blocks: 0x00016001-0x00018000
  Free inodes: 0x000054e9-0x00005ca0
Group 12: (Blocks 0x00018001-0x00018fff) csum 0xa94e [INODE_UNINIT, ITABLE_ZEROED]
…
```

Thus, we can

```bsh
# preparation
truncate -s 100M ext4.img
mkfs.ext4 ext4.img
partition=ext4.img
targetdir=unused_blocks

# dump, filter
dump=$(dumpe2fs -x "${partition}")

blocksize=$(( $(echo "${dump}" | sed -n 's/Block size: *\(.*\)$/\1/p') ))
echo "Block Size ${blocksize}"

freeblocks=$(echo "${dump}" | sed -n 's/ \+Free blocks: \(.\+\)$/\1/p')

mkdir "${targetdir}"

totalsize=0
for blockrange in ${freeblocks}; do
  beginning=$(( "${blockrange%-*}"   ))
  ending=$(( "${blockrange##*-}"  ))
  length=$(( ${ending} - ${beginning} + 1 ))
  echo "Block found: ${blockrange} start ${beginning} (${blockrange%-*}) end ${ending} (${blockrange##*-}) length ${length}"
  dd "if=${partition}" "of=${targetdir}/${blockrange}.img" "bs=${blocksize}" "skip=${beginning}" "count=${length}"
  totalsize=$(( ${totalsize} + ${length} ))
done
echo "total size: ${totalsize}"
```

to get a directory full with block-labeled ranges containing the raw image of these free blocks.

---

Note that on many storage devices (mostly SSDs, but I don't know whether your partition might not actually be e.g. an LVM thin volume or a ceph block storage device), there's not going to be any data there – the `discard` operation that ext4 (and most other filesystems these days) support can tell the underlying storage device that it's free to actually throw away the data in these blocks – which would actually lead to you getting zero'd out blocks when trying to access these.

---

found out that under rare conditions, you can have a "Free blocks:" entry that contains a single entry followed by a comma, followed by a range. You'll have to add parsing for that...

Comment: why would you need to use `-x` for hexadecimal block numbers?

Comment: @Bravo in fact you don't; before posting this I briefly checked the source code of `dump2efs` and though the non-hex, long long print of block numbers was localized, and I didn't like that, but it seems I was wrong upon re-reading.